# Convert items in a text box into an array?

Tags: apex, trigger

Here is the situation.

I have a serious of items in a text box, for example, Item1, Item2, Item3, and so on.

How can I convert those items into an array of values within a trigger?

Thank you,
Kevin

Comment: Hi Kevin, as is, your question has been flagged as Too broad, there are many ways of achieving this. Ideally, you might want to include what you have tried and where you are stuck alongside your code and describe a specific problem with enough details to be able to help. please note this is not a free coding site. Please review [ask] for additional details. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets say

```
String str = 'item1, item2, item3';
```

Then you can convert above into list by doing:

```
List<String> mylist = str.split(', ');
```

mylist will have ['item1','item2','item3']

**--added--**
Another solution to deal with extra spaces:

```
List<String> mylist = str.split(',');
for(String st : mylist) st.trim();
```

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you.